# How can I syntax-highlight non-inlined code?

Tags: editors, emacs, org-mode, literate-programming

One of the delights of using org-mode to edit LaTeX documents is the ability to see figures inline, as I am editing the buffer.

By runnning `(org-toggle-inline-images)`
, bound by default to <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-v</kbd>,
on

```
* Section Title
[[./figure.png]]
```

[image: figure visible in buffer]

the figure is visible within the buffer. (It's not perfect, since two figures,
one raster for Emacs and another vector for LaTeX, must be maintained,
but that's good enough.)

Likewise it's ideal to see code fragments within the Emacs buffer by using
`org-transclusion`.

```
#+transclude: [[file:prog.py]]
```

[image: syntax highlighting is lost]

But then I lose syntax highlighting, both within the Emacs buffer and
in the pdflatex output—syntax highlighting that is easy to obtain when
I cut-and-paste the code.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python
print("Greetings!")
#+END_SRC
```

[image: code syntax highlighted both in buffer and in LaTeX output]

How can I syntax-highlight transcluded code?

(The objective of course is to maintain the source code in just one place, and to be able to run it easily to ensure that it functions as advertised.)

Comment: The maintainer of `org-transclude` offers a video tutorial for transcluding src-blocks: https://youtu.be/ueaPiA622wA